# How to select Values from Datatable which appears once

Tags: c#, asp.net

myDataTable has a column named `ORDER_NO`. I would like to select the rows from this table which appears once. If a value appears two times than it should not selected. 
`ORDER_NO` contain Values

```
1000A
1001A
1001B
1002A
1002B
1002C
1000A
1001A
1001B
```

I want to select only form the values above are:

```
1002A
1002B
1002C
```

as they appears once in the column. Can anyone help?

Comment: _has a row named "ORDER_NO"_ ??

Comment: I'm sure he meant column...at least I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want only unique rows according to the `ORDER_NO` column?

Presuming that it's a string column you could use LINQ's `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var uniqueRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("ORDER_NO"))
    .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => group.First());
```

if you want a new `DataTable` from the unique rows you can use:

```
table = uniqueRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

If you instead only want this column's values:

```
IEnumerable<string> unqiueOrderNumbers = uniqueRows.Select(row => row.Field<string>("ORDER_NO"));
```

Comment: It display distinct records. I want the records which appears once in the row.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasIqbal: you mean "once in the table"? it's doing exacly that. It only returns rows where the `ORDER_NO` is unique in the whole table, so where there is no other row with that `ORDER_NO`. Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes. I have tried the code. But the code is returning some Duplicate values too.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasIqbal: then you don't have `Where(group => group.Count() == 1)` or there are invisible letters like empty spaces, tabs or new-lines or one is `Abc` and the other `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Tim's answer you can also use DataView to simplify this thing

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "ORDER_NO");
```

I think this is the simplest way to get distinct values from any table. You can even mention multiple columns in the ToTable method. Just pass column name as argument like ORDER_NO is send in above sample code.